# "Insufficient Permission" to retrieve user youtube subscriptipns after getting access token

Tags: youtube, permissions, youtube-api, access-token, subscriptions

I'm working on a scripts that checks if the user is already subscribed to my channel. The idea is to get all the channels the user had subscribed into then check if my channel id is one of them. First I get the access token correctly using POST and it works fine than send these as GET but the result is "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden  false". Doc page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#request_url

```
$data =file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet
&maxResults=50&access_token='.$token.'&mine=true&key=My API Key');
var_export($data);
```

and pasting the full url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&access_token={Access_Token}
```

I get this

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
  }
  ],
 "code": 403,
 "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a heaer:

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.DwG_A_V6cybZ2KGqRwPMBF02w0sYw9msqSKoCBI53So0zzIHFRKlwEv68C4aI_NdadQ4wKHUrV2pBA

key is your client id

Answer (score 0):

Google restricts access with API keys. If you go over the free limits, they charge you. You need to get a Google API key and add it to the URL like this: &key=YOUR_API_KEY

Create the API key from Google's console (you'll need to sign up and create a project): https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Your new URL for the request would be:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&access_token={Access_Token}&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error, and I solved it when I found out I needed to add the Youtube scope to my OAuth sign-in request: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"